# Gate ability definition for guest user not working

Tags: laravel

I am using the Authorization feature in Laravel (7.12.0) for my api. the Authentication is provided via Passport. In my AuthServiceProviders provider boot() method I am defining abilities with the Gate (Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate) facade. But somehow the block is not pocessed when I don't send the bearer within the header (when trying as guest). According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#guest-users) :

> By default, all gates and policies automatically return false if the
>   incoming HTTP request was not initiated by an authenticated user.
>   However, you may allow these authorization checks to pass through to
>   your gates and policies by declaring an "optional" type-hint or
>   supplying a null default value for the user argument definition

So I should be able to get into the block with $user as null. But the Gate block is not processed at all.

```
\Gate::define('foo-ability', function(?User $user){
    \Log::debug("got into Gate block");
    \Log::debug(print_r($user,1));
    if ($user){
        \Log::info('authed');
        return true;
    }else{
        \Log::info('unauthed');
        return true;
    }
});
```

What could be the reason. Why does it skip the Gate block?

Edit (mrhn):
I call the Gate from PermissionCheck middleware which is added to Kernel $middlewareGroups api array.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ( \Gate::allows( \Route::current()->getName() ) ) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return response(['message'=>'No permission.'], 401);
}
```

when I run a route(user.inded) with a guest (without bearer) that is within the middleware group then I get:

```
"message": "Unauthenticated."
```

Comment: Show the code how you call the gate and what happens when you call it without the bearer?

Comment: @mrhn and by the way, at the time I get the `"message": "Unauthenticated."` response no logs are written.

Comment: are you certain that \Route::current()->getName() returns 'foo-ability'. Try dd(\Route::current()->getName());

Comment: @mrhn no that is just test purpose "foo-ability". in the project it is defined by $permission->route_name and "user.index". I checked it anyway as you said but the route is not hitting the middleware at all. but as soon I give the bearer it hits the middleware and all blocks work.

Comment: but if you are not authenticated you cant hit that middleware or?

Comment: You are absolutely right @mrhn. The point is that the middleware is within the auth:api and the "user.index" route is as well. But the auth:api requires the authorization so the bearer, else it won't process the other middlewares. When I move the route out of the group (auth:api) then it works. So I guess I have to make another route group and add the middleware afterwards. Well thats it. Thank you for the orientation.